# Probability for a randomly selected number be algebraic.

Tags: probability

Let us select a number randomly from $[0,1]$. **What is the probability that the number will be algebraic?**

I have no idea.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does "let's pick a number at random" means "let's use the obvious uniform distribution to pick a number"? It is best to avoid making obvious assumptions and instead just specify the distribution.

Comment: I did not ask this question if all these were knew to me. Will the answer be different if we consider different distributions ?

Comment: Of course. Depending on the distribution, the probability for an algebraic number can be any number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Please explain it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The set of algebraic numbers is countable. So has measure $0$. Hence the probability is $0$

Comment: What will be the probability space?

Comment: $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The set of algebraic numbers is countable, and therefore so is the set of algebraic numbers in our interval.  Any countable set has measure $0$.

Comment: What will be the probability space and probability measure?

Comment: A natural choice is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ (so uniform distribution). But the same will be true for example for any measure on $[0,1]$ that assigns $0$ measure to points.

Comment: The word is "atomless".

Comment: ... or "non-atomic"